# Redirecionamento em CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto usando o *framework* codeigniter.

Na `index` que faz a renderização do site, eu gostaria de primeiro direcionar a uma pasta chamada 'entrada', e ao clicar num link nesta pasta, entra então na pasta 'site', que no caso é a pasta default.

Minha dúvida é: Se eu colocar um `index.html` com um *redirect* em *javascript*, não irá funcionar, porque o principal é o *php*, e se eu altero o *php*, não irá abrir o site no clique.

O que me sugerem?

Comment: Acho que a sua pergunta pode ser um pouco melhorada para compreendermos melhor a sua situação. Tente explicar um pouco o contexto. As pastas que você se refere são os `Controllers`?

Comment: Na verdade, eu tenho uma url fora do /site, onde ficam os controllers e etc... E precisava acessar ela antes de acessar o site, pois é uma pagina de entrada, ai quando clicar em entrar, faria o acesso...

Answer (score 2):

Para a criação do modal, faça o seguinte:

1. Passe um parâmetro para a view indicando se deve exibir um modal
2. Na view verifique o valor dessa variável, e se o valor for positivo (verdadeiro) adicione o conteúdo do modal;
3. Utilize essa mesma variável para adicionar um código `javascript` para exibir o modal.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

1. No controller

```html
$this->load->view('minha_view', array('exibirModal' => TRUE));
```

2. Na view - conteúdo do modal

```html
<?php
        if ($exibirModal) {
            
    ?>
        <!-- 
          Aqui vai o modal
          Como montar um modal BS: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
        -->
        <div id="modal"></div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

3. Na view - exibição do modal

```html
 <?php
        if ($exibirModal) {
            <!-- Aqui vai o modal -->
    ?>
            <script>
                $('#modal').modal();
            </script>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Isso já deve suprir a sua necessidade.

Comment: Não é isso... Acho que eu farei da seguinte forma: Vou construir um módulo auxiliar, pra gerenciar essa entrada, nele vou montar apenas o view, sem o restante do site, e com isso eu consigo controlar a entrada e os redirecionamentos...

Comment: Qual a necessidade de passar o usuário por uma tela antes da entrada? Não poderia exibir este conteúdo em um modal?

Comment: Também seria uma opção Richard, mas não sei como elaborar isso.. tendo em vista que já temos o bootstrap instalado também.. não sei se vai dar conflito e tals

Comment: Justamente o contrário, o bootstrap auxiliaria na criação do modal

Comment: Sim, mas não saberia elaborar.